# How to get all file names under static folder in NuxtJs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a frontend in NuxtJs. I want to list out all the PDFS stored under the static folder and make a dynamic link to open those documents in the browser as a separate window.
So I want to get the list of all the files of specific folder.

Comment: Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3] in addition to this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nuxt.config.js` uses fs module as default loader.
we can add this snippet of code to the `Nuxt.config.js` file and store the response to the env variable so that it can be used anywhere.

```
const fs = require('fs')
// To read Static Files
const files = fs.readdirSync('./static/pdfs')
process.env.STATIC_REFERRAL_DOCS = files
```